# IllegalArgumentException while Neo4j import

Tags: csv, neo4j, data-import

I am trying to import data from multiple files using Neo4j import-tool. However, each time I try to import the nodes using this command I get an error:

```
bin/neo4j-admin import --database test.db --mode csv --nodes:Member "import/members_headers.csv,import/members/members1.csv,import/members/members2.csv,import/members/members3.csv" --ignore-duplicate-nodes=true --ignore-missing-nodes=true
```

This is the error I get:

```
Import error: '20'
Caused by:'20'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: '20'
    at org.neo4j.csv.reader.Extractors.valueOf(Extractors.java:155)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.DataFactories$DefaultNodeFileHeaderParser.entry(DataFactories.java:317)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.DataFactories$AbstractDefaultFileHeaderParser.create(DataFactories.java:175)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.ParallelInputEntityDeserializer.<init>(ParallelInputEntityDeserializer.java:86)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputGroupsDeserializer.createNestedIterator(InputGroupsDeserializer.java:113)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputGroupsDeserializer.createNestedIterator(InputGroupsDeserializer.java:38)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.NestingIterator.fetchNextOrNull(NestingIterator.java:68)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.peek(PrefetchingIterator.java:60)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:46)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.IteratorBatcherStep.nextBatchOrNull(IteratorBatcherStep.java:63)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.InputIteratorBatcherStep.nextBatchOrNull(InputIteratorBatcherStep.java:46)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.PullingProducerStep.process(PullingProducerStep.java:43)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ProducerStep$1.run(ProducerStep.java:61)
```

I checked that this number changes for each file, for members1.csv it's 20, for members3.csv it's 48 and so on. I have practically 200 files for this node and I can't check all the fields by hand. How can I find out what columns cause this error or whatever else?

UPDATE:
A listing of rows:

```
"member_id:ID(Member)","bio","city","country","hometown","joined","lat:FLOAT","link","lon:FLOAT","member_name","state","member_status","visited","group_id:INT"
10206,Met fan from birth born the same year as Shea,New York,us,not_found,2008-02-18 18:10:20,40.73,http://www.meetup.com/members/10206,-73.99,John Hammer,NY,active,2008-02-18 18:10:20,403117
55155,not_found,New York,us,not_found,2002-10-02 19:58:03,40.75,http://www.meetup.com/members/55155,-73.97,Barbara,NY,active,2009-10-16 21:54:33,85422
73470,not_found,San Francisco,us,not_found,2002-11-08 20:37:59,37.78,http://www.meetup.com/members/73470,-122.42,tchangsf,CA,active,2004-08-05 02:48:10,54659
95940,Let's see I started watching anime heavily around 2007 with Bleach and Naruto. Turns out I had been watching anime for years once I found out voltron was GoLion.,Chicago,us,not_found,2014-01-23 17:53:20,41.94,http://www.meetup.com/members/95940,-87.75,Joshua Rose,IL,active,2014-07-14 14:07:24,12220382
171642,After a recent trip to Guatemala for Spanish classes I am looking to keep my conversational Spanish in practice,New York,us,not_found,2014-02-19 21:59:38,40.76,http://www.meetup.com/members/171642,-73.97,Alice,NY,active,2016-06-08 15:07:18,145951
183955,not_found,San Francisco,us,not_found,2016-05-03 02:54:55,37.76,http://www.meetup.com/members/183955,-122.44,Cedrick A,CA,active,2017-10-31 05:13:15,618694
205837,not_found,New York,us,New York,2015-03-16 18:34:03,40.75,http://www.meetup.com/members/205837,-73.99,Biz,NY,active,2015-03-20 00:54:02,1413487
230634,not_found,New York,us,not_found,2009-09-13 16:51:39,40.75,http://www.meetup.com/members/230634,-73.99,kstravis,NY,active,2010-09-11 18:16:31,1488352
```

Comment: What do the CSV files look like? Can you list the first few rows? Also, there appears to be a blank space in the command you gave: `.../members1.csv,,import/members/members2...` there is a set of two commas, is that intended?

Comment: @RebeccaNelson This coma is accidental here, it is not in my original query. Also, I have listed a few rows from the file.

Comment: This is going to be very hard to track down without your exact files or a minimal, complete, verifiable example. Can you isolate the error to a small subset of your data? I've found that leaving out half the files to find which half the error is in usually works okay. Then repeat that for the half that produces the error, eventually coming to a smaller and smaller set of data that can produce the error. That should help to find where the problem data is.

Comment: @RebeccaNelson I solved the problem by combining all the small files into one big including headers. Import tool for some reason could not process all these files and I didn't find out why